# recursive copying of files and folders and sub folders

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the function i have written to copy directories and files. It just copies the directories and files once. How can i copy the files from source folder to destination folder only if the file does not exist?

here is the function. Basically i want to copy the folder labref in analyst_uploads and its content to the second folder store_for_issue. If a file is uploaded to the source folder on the same day, the files should be copied to the destination folder  'store_for_issue'. Create folder if does not exist or update the contents

```
   public  function full_copy(  ) {
      $labref=  $this->uri->segment(3);     
      $source='analyst_uploads/'.date('Y').'/'.date('M').'/'.$labref;
      $newfolder='store_for_issue';
      if(is_dir($newfolder)){
          mkdir($newfolder.'/'.$labref,0777,TRUE);
      }
      $target=$newfolder.'/'.$labref.'/';
      copy( $source, $target );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public  function full_copy(  ) {
      $labref=  $this->uri->segment(3);     
      $source='analyst_uploads/'.date('Y').'/'.date('M').'/'.$labref;
      $newfolder='store_for_issue';
      if(!is_dir($newfolder)){
          mkdir($newfolder.'/'.$labref,0777,TRUE);
      }
      $target=$newfolder.'/'.$labref.'/';
      shell_exec('cp -ur '. $source . ' ' . $target);
}
```

This uses linux `cp -ur` and will only copy files that don't exist in target directory, or replace files in target directory that are older than the source files. It will operate recursively.

Of course if you wanted a PHP-only solution, you could perhaps use a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` or similar to iterate through all the files in the source directory and compare/copy them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!file_exists($target)) {
   copy( $source, $target );
}
```